# Decrypt exception when calling a model with $with

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

I have 3 models,
User, Host and URL

Basically, URL has a host_id field, so that I could relate the 2 models together.

Here are my models:

**User Model** *(user_urls is just a pivot table containing user_id and url_id)*

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
   ... irrelevant codes here...

   public function urls(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Models\SEO\Url', 'user_urls', 'user_id', 'url_id')->withTimestamps();
   }
}
```

**Host model:**

```
class Host extends Model
{

 protected $fillable = [
  'friendly_name', 
  'hosting_cost', 
  'login_url',     
  'username', //encrypted field
  'password'  //encrypted field
  ];

 ...some irrelevant codes here...

  -- MUTATORS/ACCESSORS---

  public function setPasswordAttribute($value){
     $this->attributes['password'] = \Crypt::encrypt($value); 
    }

    public function getPasswordAttribute($value){
      return $this->attributes['password'] = \Crypt::decrypt($value); 
    }

 ...

}
```

**URL model:**

```
class Url extends Model
{
     protected $table = 'urls';
     protected $with = ['host'];


     public function host(){
       return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\SEO\Host', 'host_id');
     }

}
```

Now, when I try to do this on a controller,

```
return $this->user->urls();
```

It returns an exception

```
in BaseEncrypter.php line 44
at BaseEncrypter->getJsonPayload('password') in Encrypter.php line 96
at Encrypter->decrypt('password') in Facade.php line 218
at Facade::__callStatic('decrypt', array('password')) in Host.php line 69
at Crypt::decrypt('password') in Host.php line 69
at Host->getPasswordAttribute('password') in Model.php line 2782
at Model->mutateAttribute('password', 'password') in Model.php line 2794
at Model->mutateAttributeForArray('password', 'password') in Model.php line 2529
at Model->attributesToArray() in Model.php line 2490
at Model->toArray() in Model.php line 2600
at Model->relationsToArray() in Model.php line 2492
at Model->toArray() in Model.php line 2480
at Model->jsonSerialize() in Collection.php line 1005
at Collection->Illuminate\Support\{closure}(object(Url))
at array_map(object(Closure), array(object(Url), object(Url), object(Url))) in Collection.php line 1013
at Collection->jsonSerialize() in Collection.php line 1024
at Collection->toJson() in Response.php line 68
at Response->morphToJson(object(Collection)) in Response.php line 46
at Response->setContent(object(Collection)) in Response.php line 197
at Response->__construct(object(Collection)) in Router.php line 1030
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(Collection)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 95
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Authenticate.php line 28
at Authenticate->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Authenticate), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(UsersUrlController), object(Route), object(Request), 'api_filter') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), '\App\Http\Controllers\Users\UsersUrlController', 'api_filter') in Route.php line 174
at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 703
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 705
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 678
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 654
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 59
```

I can clearly see that it is trying to decrypt a string "password", of course it will throw an error simply because it is not encrypted, but on my database it is encrypted. Why is it already encrypted before even being decrypted? Is this a possible bug?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try updating your `getPasswordAttribute()` method to just `return \Crypt::decrypt($value);`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try:

```
public function urls(){
return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Models\SEO\Url', 'user_urls', 'user_id', 'url_id');
}
```

And call the property like this:

```
$user=User->with('urls')->where('id',$id)->first();
$user->urls->create_at;
```